# How exactly can I use MITK through Qt?

Tags: qt, vtk, itk

I am new to MITK and Qt. I have downloaded and built the MITK superbuild.
But I do not understand how can I use it afterwards.
Does anyone know a good tutorial regarding using Qt and MITK to create 
a simple GUI application?

I have tried on the net to find a walk through, but it doesn't exist.
Everything seems confusing and complicated. I would appreciate your assistance to this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MITK official tutorial is pretty straight forward. See http://docs.mitk.org/nightly-qt4/Step01Page.html